# Docker on windows can mount a folder for nginx container but not for ubuntu

Tags: docker, ubuntu, dockerfile, docker-container

I am building an image from this docker file for NGinx

```
FROM nginx
COPY html /usr/share/nginx/html
```

I then run the container using this command

```
docker run -v /C/nginx/html:/usr/share/nginx/html -p 8081:80 -d --name cntr-mynginx mynginx:abc
```

This works and I am able to mount the folder and the changes made in the `html` folder on the host can be seen when within the container file system. The edits made on the container filesystem under the `/usr/share/nginx/html` folder are visible on the host as well.

Why does the same not work when I use an Ubuntu base? This is the docker file for the Ubuntu container I am trying to spin up.

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
COPY html /home
```

I used this command to run it

```
docker run -v /C/ubuntu-only/html:/home -p 8083:8080  --name cntr-ubuntu img-ubuntu:abc
```

The command above runs and when I do a `docker ps -a`, I see that the container stopped as soon as it started.

I removed the copy of the html and made the ubuntu image even more smaller by keeping just the first line `FROM ubuntu:18.04` and even then I get the same result. Container Exited almost soon as it started. Any idea why this works for NGINX but not for Ubuntu and what do I need to do to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are experiencing does not have to do with mounting a directory into your container.

> The command above runs and when I do a docker ps -a, I see that the container stopped as soon as it started.

The container is exiting due to the fact that there is no process being specified for it to run.

In the NGINX case, you can see that a [CMD instruction](https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/5971de30c487356d5d2a2e1a79e02b2612f9a72f/mainline/buster/Dockerfile#L103) is set at the end of the Dockerfile.

```
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

This starts NGINX as a foreground process, and prevents the container from exiting immediately.

The [Ubuntu Dockerfile](https://github.com/tianon/docker-brew-ubuntu-core/blob/cfb552709a84c4732eedf2ff89ac2e46f62ba4f8/bionic/Dockerfile#L42) is different in that it specifies bash as the command the container will run at start.

```
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

Because bash does not run as a foreground process here, the container exits immediately.

Try augmenting your `docker run` command to include a process that stays in the foreground, like `sleep`.

```
docker run -v /C/ubuntu-only/html:/home -p 8083:8080  --name cntr-ubuntu img-ubuntu:abc sleep 9000
```

If you run `docker exec -it cntr-ubuntu /bin/bash` you should find yourself inside the container and verify that the mounted directory is present.

Comment: thanks for your reply. my nginx docker is just the two lines that I have put in the comment above. I dont have a CMD issued at the end so not sure why that would cause a problem.

Comment: The images you are inheriting from do have the CMD instruction, though. Because you are using those images as the base for your image, the CMD instruction passes through to your image.

Comment: actually its not that. I finally found out that I was missing one flag in the docker run command. I had to put `-it` and keeping everything else the same as in my question, I got the container running without any issues or even putting sleep.